# comparing the page's url to a's href

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

i am trying  to do that when the page's url equals the `<a>`'s href than it will change something's class.

it does changes the page on a click on the link, but it doesnt change the class of the `<li>`

here is what i have done:

html:

```
<div id='settingNev' >
    <ul >
        <li id="L1"  runat="server"><a id="A1" href="../newsFeed/allEr.aspx" runat="server"><span>Er</span></a></li>
        <li id="L2" runat="server"><a id="A2" href="../newsFeed/allEe.aspx" runat="server"><span>Ee</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

code behind:

```
if (A1.HRef.ToString() == Request.Url.ToString())
    {
        L1.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
    } 
if (A2.HRef.ToString() == Request.Url.ToString())
    {
        L2.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
    }
```

the class active works, i have checked it.
by the way this code is on a master page connected to both pages in the `<div id='settingNev' >`.

Tnx for the help :D

Comment: I suspect the comparison is considering the full URL, and it's highly unlikely that `http://www.yoursite.com/newsFeed/allEr.aspx` and `../newsFeed/allEr.aspx` will ever match

Comment: so what is the allternative?

Comment: Also be careful... the url may contains url query string parameters. Take a look at the `Uri` class in the .Net Framework. There are plenty of useful methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the relative url to absolute in order to compare with the page url.

For some odd reason, I couldn't find any Url helper that supports parent paths in URL so the only workaround I can think of is using `Server.MapPath()` for this:

```
string pagePath = Server.MapPath(Request.FilePath);
Dictionary<HtmlAnchor, Label> anchorMapping = new Dictionary<HtmlAnchor, Label>();
anchorMapping.Add(A1, L1);
anchorMapping.Add(A2, L2);
foreach (HtmlAnchor currentAnchor in anchorMapping.Keys)
{
    if (Server.MapPath(currentAnchor.HRef).Equals(pagePath))
    {
        anchorMapping[currentAnchor].Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problme is **A1.HRef** returns **relative** url. On the other hands, **Request.Url** returns **absolute** url.

In order to fix it, you want to use server control for hyper link, and resolve it back to absolute path.

```
<ul>
    <li id="L1" runat="server">
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="A1HyperLink" 
            NavigateUrl="~/newsFeed/allEr.aspx">
            <span>Er</span>
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </li>
</ul>

string url = Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
string a1 = ResolveUrl(A1HyperLink.NavigateUrl);
if (string.Equals(a1, url, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
{
    L1.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
}
```

### Another method

Resolve A1's relative path to **absolute** path using **ResolveUrl**

```
<div id='settingNev' >
    <ul >
        <li id="L1"  runat="server"><a id="A1" 
           href="../newsFeed/allEr.aspx" 
           runat="server"><span>Er</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

string url = Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
string a1 = ResolveUrl(A1.HRef);
if (string.Equals(a1, url, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
{
    L1.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
}
```